# What does "destination" means on Deployment "Remove Additional Files"

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

I want to replace the files whenever I deploy. Instead of replacing the existing ones, they just add up to the folder because each filenames are dynamically made.

I came across this "Remove additional files" default **false** and could be a solution to my problem.

However, while reading the description, the "destination" is kind of vague. Documentation [here](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/azure-deployments/deploying-a-package-to-an-azure-web-app)

> When True instructs Web Deploy to delete files from the destination
>   that aren't in the source package

Is the "destination" pertains to the **physical path**?

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the files"? Do you want to clear the folder before deploying?

Comment: Yes, But only for the items to be deployed in physical path.

Comment: if you select `Custom Installation Directory` step, there will be a 'Purge` option. Otherwise I think you might need to include a pre-deployment PS script.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, the destination will be the value of the **Physical Path** setting.

I think the setting that will be of value to you is the **File comparison method**. It indicates the algorithm by which comparisons will be made to determine which files, if any, should be updated by the package.

[This](https://octopus.com/blog/reliably-deploying-large-azure-web-apps) link is to a blog post in which the Timestamp and Checksum algorithms are discussed. I have included a portion of this post below.

> ### Timestamp instead of checksum
>
> In Octopus 3.0 we decided to make
>   Checksum the default (and only choice) for syncing files with
>   WebDeploy. Using checksum we would only deploy files which had
>   actually changed, without needing any special configuration. This
>   reduces the time and bandwidth required for subsequent deployments to
>   the same web app. This works really nicely for moderate sized
>   applications but, as we discovered, becomes prohibitively slow and
>   unreliable for large applications.
>
> If you find yourself in this situation you can switch to using
>   Timestamp for file comparison instead of Checksum using Octopus Deploy
>   3.3.3 or newer.
>
> **Timestamp**
>
> If you have any existing Azure Web App steps you will need to update
>   them to use timestamp and create a new release. Any new Azure Web App
>   steps you create will use timestamp by default, but you can always
>   switch to checksum if that suits your needs better.
>
> If you prefer checksum, we are planning to upgrade to
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.3.6.0 which has several bug fixes for
>   checksum comparisons.
>
> **Preserving timestamps**
>
> The downside with using timestamps for file
>   comparison is reliability - you can easily get false-positives -
>   that's why checksum is so attractive. If you are using NuGet packages
>   the timestamp of your files will be lost when they are unpacked
>   meaning every file appears to be newer and will be uploaded regardless
>   of whether it has changed - more detail. To work around this, consider
>   using zip packages - we have automated tests proving the timestamps
>   are preserved end-to-end through your deployments.